# Dynamically checking and allocating SLURM nodes within a python script

Tags: python, distributed-computing, hpc, slurm

I have a computationally expensive simulation function I am looking to distribute accross a multi-node cluster. The code looks something like this:

```
input_tasks = [input_0, input_1, ..., input_n]
for i in input_tasks:
    expensive_function(i)
```

I am running the code from a node with high compute and I am looking to distribute the function inputs to many nodes with varying compute power. The highest compute nodes should take priority and always pick up the next task if they are free. A pseudocode of what I wish to do is written below.

```
input_tasks = [input_0, input_1, ..., input_n]
available_nodes_ranked_by_compute = [node_0, node_1, ..., etc]
While(input_tasks): 
   i = input_tasks.pop(0)
   #get best current node or wait for a node to free up
   node_i = available_nodes_ranked_by_compute.pop(0)
   expensive_function(i, node_i)
   #add node back to avaiable node list when its done
   available_nodes_ranked_by_compute.append(node_i)
   #re-sort available nodes by compute
```

I am relatively new to distributed computing and SLURM usage, so I am unsure how to check whether a particular node is being currently used (in the context of the python script). I want a way to maintain a dynamic list/heap that maintains the currrently unused nodes on the cluster so I can use it to execute all my tasks. Is there a way to do this?